# need some assistance on a forum code mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

im having problems with this code

```
<?php
include '01.php';
include 'header.php';
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories WHERE cat_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.' . mysql_error();
}
else
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo 'This category does not exist.';
    }
    else
    {
        //display category data
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '<h2>Topics in ′' . $row['cat_name'] . '′ category</h2>';
        }

        //do a query for the topics
        $sql = "SELECT  
                    topic_id,
                    topic_subject,
                    topic_date,
                    topic_cat
                FROM
                    topics
                WHERE
                    topic_cat = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'The topics could not be displayed, please try again later.';
        }
        else
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
            {
                echo 'There are no topics in this category yet.';
            }
            else
            {
                //prepare the table
                echo '<table border="1">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Topic</th>
                        <th>Created at</th>
                      </tr>'; 

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {               
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="leftpart">';
                            echo '<h3><a href="topic.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a><h3>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="rightpart">';
                            echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['topic_date']));
                        echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

the error it gives me is this The category could not be displayed, please try again later.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 **strong text **
 $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories WHERE  keeps not working for some reason**strong text**
would really appreciate the help i dont know what to do anymore googled everywhere and tried different combinations but cant get the id from cat_id please help

Comment: what is an example url you are getting the $_GET['id';] from?

Comment: xxxxx.com/category.php?id

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions in PHP are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for information on why and what to replace them with.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices.

Comment: thank you for the advice but i have less than 2 weeks for my final assignement (dont ask why) so i cant really redo most of the things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you don't have proper quote. you should enclose the result of your `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])`  inside `'` 
like the sample below

```
"SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description 
      FROM categories WHERE cat_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'";
```

if you want try to  use  a simplified query remember the quotes this way:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description 
              FROM categories WHERE cat_id = '" .$id . "';");
```

but for debugging try

```
var_dump($id); 

var_dump($sql);
```

and check if $id contain a proper value and $sql is correctly formed (try copy the resulting query and execute it in your console)

then if the query give you the right result in console this mean the resulting query is right..

PS the url should be

```
xxxxx.com/category.php?id=1
```

remember to assign a value to your id

Comment: hmm tried it thanks the error didnt show up but for some reason the if code that echos this category doesnt exist pops up even though i have like tons of em already on the server

Comment: 1) for debugging try var_dump( mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])) before the $sql and check if contain proper value .. 2) be sure the value you provided for query cat_id really match the value in db..

Comment: i also tried this $sql = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description 
      FROM categories WHERE cat_id = " .$id); and it says the query is empty any tips?

Comment: ive been trying to get this forum to work for like 8 hours now and my mind is totally messed up with this

Comment: NULL resource(5) of type (mysql result) heres the weird thing when i just use select from categories and use the rest of the code then it echo all the category names so the cat_id is faulty?

Comment: Then this mean you $id don't contain the expected value .. please post the exact url  you  getting the $_GET['id';] from?

Comment: Anyway i have update the answer be sure you assign a proper value to id in url  eg:   ?id=1

Comment: xxxxxx.com/PHP/category.php?id is the url for some reason when i try to get to the topics

Comment: You must assign a proper value to id  should be xxxxxx.com/PHP/category.php?id=2

Comment: thank you for your support i solved the problem the guide that im using is a bit dated maybe 6 years and the solution is pretty idk screwed up $sql="SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description 
      FROM categories WHERE cat_id ";     like thats it.... nothing else... and everything will popup... my head hurts but ty for your help

Comment: your answer helps me get the code working half way it works but there something bad in my code. i just had to change it to WHERE cat_id "; so my table will pop up i guess the rest of the code has a mistake in it

Comment: well if my answer is right and give you right solution or solved the error you showed  is fair mark it as accepeted .. if my answer i swrong and don't help you obviously should rate negatively ..